# How Can I remove an object with value null from a mongodb database on ruby on rails, only using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have an object that sometimes create a bug that inserts a object in it's array ta associates many objects:

`Bookshelf.books` that returns an array of objects `Book` that have a `field type`
sometimes it generates a `Book` object like `<Book id:some_number, type:fixed_type>` that's not valid and not expected to be created.
If i connect to the Mongodb via Compass it shows me a null file in the association of `Bookshelf.books`
Assuming that I can't access the db through Compass anymore, and trying to delete eg.

```
Bookshelf.books.delete_at(book_index)
Bookshelf.books[book_index].delete
Bookshelf.books[book_index].destroy
Bookshelf.books[book_index].destroy!
```

this `Book` and after saving it cause this `Book object` to reappear, is there a way to delete this file definitely ?

Comment: It's not the answer: looks like using a RDBMS for the relationship of books and bookshelves is better than NoSQL

Comment: What is that _"file"_ / _"null file"_ you are referring to? Also, what do you mean by _"cause this Book object to reaper"_ – is that a typo (reappear)?

Comment: Is books embed object or array of objects field Bookshelf model. if books an embedded objects you have primary _id By using this you can delete. if array of objects then use the ruby array method to remove and assign back to books update Bookshelf object.